# Entity Framework - update field value to current DB server time

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I've pulling back an entity object from a database and I need to update the date to the DB server's date/time - usually you could accomplish this by setting it with the SQL `getDate()` function.

How can I accomplish this in the following scenario:

```
var client = context.client.Where(c=>c.clientID == 1).FirstOrDefault();

// the value needs to be the value of the server's current date, i.e, getDate()... not DateTime.Now
client.someDate = <somevalue>;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: doesn't really make sense what you are doing. your retrieving an entity, updating the time then saving it again? Why don't you use a trigger to update the time?

Comment: My sample code is contrived to get the idea across about what I need in a simple manner. The actual implementation does indeed require the server's datetime. Besides, I try to avoid using db-specific things such as triggers since the product I'm working must support multiple db backends.

Answer (score 4):

Try inserting the following in place of the fourth line in your sample:

```
var dateQuery = context.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime() ");
client.SomeDate = dateQuery.AsEnumerable().First();
```

Comment: Will this defer execution until context.SaveChanges() is called? Or will it query and return the cirrent SQL date immediately?

Comment: This technique doesn't assign the database server's time when the UPDATE is performed.  If there is any appreciable work or network latency between the above AsEnumerable() and subsequent SaveChagnes(), the value will be off.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I'm doing this in an EF6/MVC5 VB.NET application.

Problem: using one query to return the `getdate()` value, then using another query to update a record with the retrieved `getdate()` value is unacceptable IMHO. That's two queries where only one ought to be required. Plus, the returned `getdate()` value technically isn't accurate by the time it's written back, since time has passed.

Solution: the below snippet updates a single nullable datetime field to the current value of `getdate()`, and returns the updated value of `getdate()` (if you don't need the value returned, just remove the `OUTPUT INSERTED.theTime` segment). All this is done in a SQL query.

```
Dim theTime As DateTime? = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of DateTime?) _
("UPDATE myTable SET theTime = getdate() OUTPUT INSERTED.theTime WHERE someRecordID = @someRecordID", New SqlParameter("@someRecordID", someRecordID)).First()
```

It seems like there must be *some* better solution (or this is a gross oversight on the part of MS, isn't using getdate() a common and proper practice while updating records?). I'd be thrilled if someone could point out a cleaner approach in the comments or a different answer.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to phrase this like:

```
Dim craftBeer = context.CraftBeers.Find(id)
... (update other craftBeer properties) ...
craftBeer.date_emptied = SqlServer.SqlFunction.GetDate
context.Entry(craftBeer).State = EntityState.Modfied
context.SaveChanges()
```

... but unfortunately, apparently SqlServer.SqlFunctions.GetDate doesn't work with EF like this.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old question, but I am having this issue too.  It just occurred to me that you could create a scalar function on the SQL Server that simply RETURNS GETDATE().  Then in entity framework, pull that SQL function into your context. Seems a little contrived, but I think it would work.

Comment: If there is any work between GetDate and Save or network latency the value will be not exactly correct.

Answer (score -1):

DateTime.Now will give the current date from your server(Web Server not the DB Server).
if client.someDate is DateTime field then you can assign DateTime.Now and update it back to the database.

Comment: I concur. However, my webserver/db server have different times so the db server is the value I need. I need the equivalent of "update client set someDate=getDate()"

Comment: [Function(Name="GetDate", IsComposable=true)]
public DateTime GetSystemDate()
{
  MethodInfo mi = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;
  return (DateTime)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, mi, new object[]{}).ReturnValue;
}

Comment: Add the above method to your datacontext class to get the db server time

Comment: @XtremeBytes this solution works for Linq to SQL, not Entity Framework

Answer (score -1):

Maybe too late, but I leave it if it can help someone, We can get the current date time from the database server with something like:

```
public DateTime GetDate()
{ 
  var date = context.client.Select(c => DateTime.Now).First(); 
  return date;
}
```

so We use the function:

```
var client = context.client.Where(c=>c.clientID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
client.someDate = GetDate();
context.client.Add(client);
```