# Update object in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an old query that looks

```
UPDATE table1 SET date_time_field = NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE WHERE ...;
```

How can I do the same in EF ? I cannot write

```
....
table1_entity.date_time_field = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

because the application and DB server may use different timezones. Is it possible to achieve this functionality without native queries (which is my current approach, but I don't really like it) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the above method to your datacontext class to get the db server time:

```
[Function(Name="GetDate", IsComposable=true)]
public DateTime GetSystemDate()
{
  MethodInfo mi = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;
  return (DateTime)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, mi, new object[]{}).ReturnValue;
}
```

Extracted from this post:

[Entity Framework - update field value to current DB server time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404086/entity-framework-update-field-value-to-current-db-server-time)

Comment: this solution works for Linq to SQL, not Entity Framework! For EF Equivalent see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683496/getdate-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to replace `DateTime.Now` with a `GetServerDatetime()` call, and use the timezone of the server. Another is to store the timezone.

What I've done in the past is create a sliding window cache (15 minutes) of the server time (i.e every 15 minutes the server time is queried and stored locally)

Comment: How do I get `Server`? Sorry, if it's a silly question, I'm quite inexperienced with EF.

Comment: @a1ex07
: that was purely figurative.  Create a method as shown by @ShahidAzim